# Create an instance of a DrawableGameComponent later in the game in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I've been struggling my mind for long now.

I have my main *Game* Class called **Game1** and a *DrawableGameComponent*-inherited *ShowUp* Class called **myShowUp**

The usual way would be to add the component **myShowUp** to the **Game1** Object so it be part of the game (directly in the Initialize method of **Game1**) as follow :

```
class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    ShowUp myShowUp;

    ...

    protected override Initialize ()
    {
        this.myShowUp = new ShowUp(this);
        this.Components.Add(this.myShowUp);
    }
    ...
}
```

This method does work and **myShowUp** is shown and becomes an independant object in the game.

What I would like is to instanciate and add the object in the game-objects-list later (e.g. after a click in the window)

This is my try :

```
class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    MouseState myMouseState;

    ...

    ...

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        myMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        if (myMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            this.myShowUp = new ShowUp(this);   // Nothing
            this.Components.Add(this.myShowUp); // Happens..
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    ...
}
```

I found a method so far, i just keep the first syntax (i.e. keep the instanciation into the Initialize method) and define a boolean into the *ShowUp* Class named **activated**.
If **activated** is true I execute the instructions to show it up or else nothing.
And in my Update method of my *Game* object i call **activate()** of **myShowUp** if my left button is pressed to change the **activated** variable to true.

This method works but I'm not quite satisfied, i wish it would have been as simple as to just instanciate the objects in my *Game* Object anywhere in the code to make them part of it.
Is there a way to make that way be ?

Something like :

```
class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    ShowUp myShowUp;
    MouseState myMouseState;

    ...

    ...

    protected override Initialize ()
    {
        this.Components.Add(this.myShowUp);
    }

    ...

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        myMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        if (myMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            this.myShowUp = new ShowUp(this);
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    ...
}
```

This would be nice.

Comment: Looking at the docs, nowhere does it say that you can't do what you want to do - it doesn't say that you need to add a component during the `Initialise` method on `Game`. I do notice that you are assigning `this.myShowUp` - is there any reason you are assigning it to a member of your subclassed `Game` instance? Can you post the `Draw` code for your `Game1` class and the code for the `ShowUp` class as I have an idea what might be the issue

Comment: @Charleh In my *Draw* method of *Game1* i don't have nothing, indeed adding the component this.myShowUp to the game (i.e. this.Components.Add(this.myShowUp)) makes us possible to override the Draw method in the DrawableGameComponent (as making a new thread to draw into the global canvas)

Comment: What about `ShowUp` - how does it know what to draw? Does DrawableGameComponent draw a placeholder if you don't override the `Draw` method? Have you overridden `DrawableGameComponent.Draw`? I've not touched XNA for a while though - can you post your `ShowUp` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one minor bug in your code. You will be creating several instances of your component - one per update. This is because you don't check either that the *previous* mouse state is `Released` or that `myShowUp` is null, before creating the component. Here's some tested working code (that checks both conditions):

```
MouseState lastMouseState;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    MouseState mouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    if(mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed
            && lastMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released
            && myShowUp == null)
    {
        Components.Add(myShowUp = new ShowUp(this));
    }

    lastMouseState = mouseState;

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

Of course - I'm not sure why this bug would cause `ShowUp` to not appear at all - as you are creating multiple instances of it - you'd expect to be able to see it. There may be a bug in your `ShowUp` component.

For what it's worth, here is the code that I tested with:

```
class ShowUp : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public ShowUp(Game game) : base(game) { }

    Texture2D texture;
    SpriteBatch sb;

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        sb = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        texture = this.Game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("test");
        base.LoadContent();
    }

    public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        sb.Begin();
        sb.Draw(texture, new Vector2(100), Color.White);
        sb.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Note that, adding a component *after* `Game.Initialize` is run will cause that component's `Initialize` and `LoadContent` methods to run as soon as it is added to the `Components` collection.

Note that, for your future reference, `DrawableGameComponent` already comes with `Enabled` and `Visible` properties - allowing you to skip over `Update` and `Draw` respectively for that instance.

Comment: does it work for you ? I even follow the same structure of your coding but still nothing happens, here are the pastebins of my code.

Comment: After few minutes of trying I figured out where the problem stands, there is a little mistake in your snippet, I changed *myShowUp != null* to *myShowUp == null* in the conditional structure of Game.Update and it finally works, thanks for your lead (change your code and i will validate your answer)

Comment: Oh crikey! My bad - sorry - thought I'd illustrate both of the checks at the last minute and introduced a bug! Glad you got it sorted :)